# Issues with OR operator in WP functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, boolean-logic

Our Wordpress website requires that some pages are only visible for users with specific roles. Currently the administrator can not access the pages specified in `$redaktor_pages` and `$mod_pages`.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'restrict_access' );
function restrict_access() {
    //pages for admins
    $admin_pages = is_page(array('veiledning-administrator', 'database'));
    //pages for redaktør
    $redaktor_pages = is_page(array('veiledning-redaktor'));
    //pages for moderators
    $mod_pages = is_page(array(''));

    //users forum role
    $forum_role = bbp_get_user_display_role( get_current_user_id() );

    if( (!current_user_can('administrator') && $admin_pages) || ( (!current_user_can('editor') || !current_user_can('administrator') ) && $redaktor_pages ) || ( ($forum_role!='moderator' || !current_user_can('administrator')) && $mod_pages) ) {
        wp_redirect('/');
        exit;
    } 
}
```

Where I use logical operators within an if-statement: `(a || b) && c` it seems like the function ignores "b".

I would expect the 'administrator' role to also be able to view pages specified within $redaktor_pages and $mod_pages seeing as it is included within the if-statement.

Logically I would expect: `(a = false || b = true) = true`

What is actually happening is that 'administrator' can not view pages that are listed within the specific variables, unless they are the $admin_pages

This makes it seem as if that part of the if-statement is treated like this: `(a = false || b = true) = false`

Comment: Try running line by line your conditions on a paper and you'll see what the issue is.

Comment: @cabrerahector managed to fix the middle part by re-arranging it like this: (!current_user_can('editor' || 'administrator') && $redaktor_pages). Still unsure about the third one though after trying different combinations of ().

Comment: `'editor' || 'administrator'` just evaluates to `true` so I don't think that would have fixed anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have 3 sets of conditions here, and if any of them evaluate to true the access is denied.

For your second and third conditions, your question says you're working with `(a || b) && c` but this is not the case. You're working with `(!a || !b) && c` which is a very different thing. Think about what the combination of `OR` and `NOT` means. Both conditions are evaluated and either one being true results in the condition being true.

So when you check if an administrator is `NOT editor OR NOT administrator` then the condition evaluates to true because they are `NOT` an editor. You want to use `AND` to check that both conditions aren't true. Checking an administrator is `NOT editor AND NOT administrator` evaluates to false.

```
function restrict_access() {
    //pages for admins
    $admin_pages = is_page(array('veiledning-administrator', 'database'));
    //pages for redaktør
    $redaktor_pages = is_page(array('veiledning-redaktor'));
    //pages for moderators
    $mod_pages = is_page(array(''));

    //users forum role
    $forum_role = bbp_get_user_display_role( get_current_user_id() );

    if(
        (!current_user_can('administrator') && $admin_pages) || 
        (!current_user_can('editor') && !current_user_can('administrator') && $redaktor_pages) ||
        ($forum_role != 'moderator' && !current_user_can('administrator') && $mod_pages)
    ) {
        wp_redirect('/');
        exit;
    } 
}
```

Note that `&&` has higher precedence than `||` so the extra parentheses you've got here are implied and unnecessary. But I find it's better to explicitly include them anyway.

Comment: That approach makes sense. Being stuck on the "Is the user an editor OR an administrator?" would most likely have confused me more over time. A further insight into the combination of OR and NOT will hopefully help me avoid these issues in the future.